# How to change font size on button click?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Here's what I've tried:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};

  this.focus = () => this.refs.editor.focus();
  this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});

  this.toggleFontSize = (fontSize) => this._toggleFontSize(fontSize);
}

_toggleFontSize(fontSize) {
  this.onChange(
    RichUtils.toggleBlockType(
      this.state.editorState,
      fontSize
    )
  );
}

<button onClick={e => this.toggleFontSize('100px')}>100px</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the fontSize is like managing any other inline style on Draftjs is a little bit tricky especially if you have so little knowledge of how the Immutable model works on the ContentState and the EditorState.
The Easiest way to customize any inline style is to use the [draft-js-custom-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-custom-styles) module.

Here is how you can toggle a fontSize on a text selection:

```
import createStyles from "draft-js-custom-styles";
const customStylesToManage = ["font-size", "color"];
const { styles, customStyleFn, exporter } = createStyles(customStylesToManage, "CUSTOM_")
//CUSTOM_ is going to be used as a prefix for you inline styles
```

Now you have to use the customStyleFn on the main Draftjs Editor for applying styles on toggle

```
<Editor customStyleFn={customStyleFn} ... />
```

For applying a specific style to a text selection you simply call toggle on style

```
const newEditorState = styles.fontSize.toggle(editorState, "27px");
```

And Make sure to update the editorState to apply the inline style

```
updateEditorState(newEditorState);
```

Other methods are supported too, for example, you can remove a style completely form a text selection, add a new style or get the current inline style value:

```
const currentFontSizeForSelectedText = styles.fontSize.current;
```

Check the module's [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-custom-styles) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

A event handler function should be declared like below and when you call in button onClick you will use this.toggleFontSize.

Just do this

```
  toggleFontSize = fontSize => {
       const { editorState } = this.state;
       RichUtils.toggleBlockType( editorState, fontSize  );
  }

  <button onClick={e => this.toggleFontSize('100px')}>100px</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add fuction `_onFontSizeClick` and then `customStyleMap` provide it to `<Editor />`

```
import { Editor, EditorState, RichUtils } from 'draft-js';

const _onFontSizeClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onEnterText(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, 'FONT_SIZE_40'));
}
const customStyleMap = {
    FONT_SIZE_40: {
      fontSize: "40px"
    }
};


<button className = "" onMouseDown = { e => { _onFontSizeClick(e)} }>H1</button>
<Editor editorState={editorState} customStyleMap={customStyleMap} />
```